# Uninstalling vagrant-proxyconf doesn't remove proxy settings

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I installed vagrant-proxyconf and added to Vagrantfile the following:

```
if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
config.proxy.http = "http://192.168.33.10:3128/"
config.proxy.https = "http://192.168.33.10:3128/"
end
```

Later I uninstalled vagrant-proxyconf and removed the above lines from Vagrantfile.

Now every time I try to use apt-get or npm i , I get this error message:

```
Failed to connect to 192.168.33.10 port 3128: Connection refused
```

So the proxy settings are still somewhere within the vagrant config, yet not in the Vagrantfile. Where else can I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed both the plugin and its config for your vm after your vm had been configured (on `vagrant up`). Now when you start your existing vm again, the configuration done by the gone plugin is still in place.

## Easiest solution: fresh install

The easiest way to get everything back is simply to `vagrant destroy` your existing machine and `vagrant up` a fresh new one.

## Deconfigure with plugin help

If for whatever reason you wish to keep your existing machine, you can:

1. `vagrant halt` if it is on
2. rerun `vagrant install vagrant-proxyconf` without any config in place
3. `vagrant up` so that the proxy is deconfigured everywhere needed,
4. `vagrant halt` the machine again
5. remove the plugin and go back to a normal life.

## Manually undo what plugin has done

The latest solution is to check what the plugin is doing exactly in your particular case (OS, provider, etc...) by analysing its [source code](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf) and remove every config done in your vm manually (environment variables, config for apt, etc...)

Comment: Marked this answer as correct. I tried your second solution: 5 easy steps and it worked like a charm! Thanks!